# Steam family sharing can both users be logged in while one is playing a game?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

From the steam family sharing [FAQ](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing)

> *Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?*
>
> No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.

My question is while two people can't play games at the same time. Can one person play a game while the other who owns the game be logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can both users be logged in while one is playing a game?

Yes, the game's owner being logged in does not prevent other users from playing the owner's shared games.